# Angular combinelatest using subject without initial value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular RXJS, I have multiple Behavior Subjects,
My problem is: I want the posts$ stream to emit initially without setting a value for the category filter when loading the page, but I don't want to set a default value for the CategorySubject!, I tried NULL  its no working and If I change it to Subject;combinelatest will not work initially, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```js
  private CategorySubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>();
  //CategorySubject = new Subject<number>();
  //CategorySubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
  public CategoryAction$ = this.CategorySubject.asObservable();

  //pageIndex Subject
  private pageIndexSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  public pageIndexAction$ = this.pageIndexSubject.asObservable();

  //Search/filter Subject
  private searchSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public searchAction$ = this.searchSubject.asObservable();

 Posts$ = combineLatest([
    this.pageIndexAction$,
    this.searchAction$
    this.CategoryAction$
  ]).pipe()
```

Comment: It should work if you provide `null` default value for `CategoryAction$`, what do you mean when you say "its no working"?

Comment: @BizzyBob I got an error "Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `strictNullChecks` enabled, you could either specify your BehaviorSubject's type as `BehaviorSubject<number|null>` or you could use a plain `Subject<number>` and use [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to emit your initial `null` value inside the `combineLatest`:

```js
 private CategoryAction$ = new Subject<number>();
 
 ...
 
 Posts$ = combineLatest([
    this.pageIndexAction$,
    this.searchAction$
    this.CategoryAction$.pipe(startWith(null))
  ]).pipe()
```